# How to apply a multi-document template

Tags: c#, docusignapi

**The general process**

1. Documents are uploaded to DocuSign creating a new Envelope.
2. Templates are applied to this Envelope.
3. Recipients are updated to make sure there is no mixup with signers from the template
4. The Envelope is sent to the signers.

**Intended use of templates**

The primary use of templates is to allow users to upload documents and use all other information from templates like fields and other setting for the uploaded documents. Signers can also be freely set and overwrite the ones defined in the template.

For applying templates we use https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopetemplates/applytodocument/

**The Template**

The template consist of 2 documents. The first document has 3 pages and the second document has 2 pages.
There is one signer. A signature box is added to the last page of both documents.

**The Problem**

1. Test scenario: The exact same documents as in the template. This results in the signature box on the second document is not set.
2. Test scenario: Use the 3 page file for both documents. This results in the signature box being put on page 3 of both documents. So it looks like the assignment works only from document 1 to all the other documents
3. Test scenario: Use different 3 page documents that match the template for both documents. The result is the same as in the 2. test scenario.

**What I tried**

The described scenarios are based on this (simplyfied) code for applying the templates:

```
//variables envAPI (class EnvelopesApi), accountId, templateId and envelope (class Envelope) are already set

DocumentTemplateList templateList = new DocumentTemplateList();
templateList.DocumentTemplates = new List<DocumentTemplate>();
templateList.DocumentTemplates.Add(new DocumentTemplate()
{
    TemplateId = templateId,
    DocumentId = "1"
});
envAPI.ApplyTemplateToDocument(accountId, envelope.EnvelopeId, "1", templateList);

templateList = new DocumentTemplateList();
templateList.DocumentTemplates = new List<DocumentTemplate>();
templateList.DocumentTemplates.Add(new DocumentTemplate()
{
    TemplateId = templateId,
    DocumentId = "2"
});
envAPI.ApplyTemplateToDocument(accountId, envelope.EnvelopeId, "2", templateList);
//some recipient checking is done here
envAPI.Update(accountId, envelope.EnvelopeId, envelope);
```

I also tried using more entries in templateList.DocumentTemplates but that only caused INVALID_REQUEST_BODY errors.
I realized the DocumentID property of the documents in the templates are very different after the first file. My test template has 1 for the first document and the ID of the second document is a very large number. Using this large number also causes INVALID_REQUEST_BODY errors.

Is this actually correct and the error is somewhere else? Because it looks like it should work this way. Or is the problem located somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: This doesn't work. At least not this way.

Yes, composite templates are one way of dealing with this requirement but then again, why do multi-document templates even exist?

So the answer is quite simple: Do it the other way around.
To use a multi-document template properly, the template needs to be the starting point. Use a template and replace the files to create an evenlope instead of creating an envelope first and then applying templates to the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow that you are trying is a perfect place to use a composite template. The recommendation is use one composite template per document. In one POST envelopes call you can swap out the documents on the templates with documents at runtime and apply server (saved) templates to the documents. You can add recipients, drop recipients by not including them, and also add tabs or write values to tabs at runtime. See:
https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-from-the-trenches-composite-templates
https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-why-use-composite-templates